# Performance of clustered index on SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, time-complexity, clustered-index

Suppose you have two tables:

```
Student(id, class) // 100 rows
Course(id, course) // 100 rows
```

Initially assume that there is no index on both the tables. Now suppose we have a query:-

```
select id, course 
from Student join course 
on student.id = Course.id and student.id = 20
```

Since you don't have any index, so you need to traverse all the rows in both tables.

```
Time complexity - O(100 x 100)
```

Now we updated the table and `Student.id` is a primary key. Clustered index will be created on it and now the overall complexity is

```
Time complexity - O(log 100) // Nested loop join
```

Do you think my assumption is correct? Could anyone help me?

Nested loop join algo is here:

[image]

Comment: I think you should not mix join + where.  `select id, course 
from Student 
join Course 
 ON student.id = Course.id WHERE student.id = 20`

Comment: Please do not use this outdated join syntax. It works but SQL Standard has `JOIN ..  ON...` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join course 
on student.id = Course.id
```

is correctly in `O(MN)` (Worst-Case), where `M` and `N` are the number of rows in the first and second table respectively, since that is an `equi-join` (Join on a `=` condition) it compares every row from the first with the second.

However, you also have a second condition. Since `SQL` has many performance-enhancing algorithms, it is very likely that the `student.id = 20` would be evaluated first. Then you would have firstly `M` (assume linear in the number of rows of the students table) to search for `student.id = 20`. Then, if `student.id = 20` is only constant, let's say m, you would have `m * N`.

All in all, `O(M + (m * N))`.

That here depends now on `m`. If `m` is constant then in the asymptotic analysis `O(M + N) = O(2M)`, since `M=N` and you end up with `O(M) = O(N)` or linear. Otherwise, if `m` is in `Omega(1)`, then it would be `O(M + M * N)` or as you assumed `O(MN)`.

Then with regards to the `PRIMARY KEY` a clustered index will/can be created. The time complexity now for future queries would be as you said `O(log K)`, where K are the rows in the new table (can be != 100).

Now why `log K`? Because relational databases structure indices as [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Overview). Then in WC you get `O(log K)` in the height of the tree.

More precisely

[image]

since on B-trees you have max. `2d children` and number of keys `s` between `d - 1 < s < 2d`. `d` is called order, degree or branching factor of the tree.

Hope it helps!